# Using previously frozen salsa

Tags: freezing, barbecue, thawing, salsa, cherries

I hope this isn't off base because I'm not asking for recipes, just suggestions that I might not have thought of.

I made a HUGE batch of roasted cherry salsa (like normal salsa but where all the ingredients except cilantro [but including the additional cherries] go on a grill for about 10 minutes in indirect heat (my husband always puts wood in with the charcoal so the salsa has a nice smoky flavor too).  It wasn't eaten as well as I'd thought (it was taken to a BBQ), leaving me with TONS of it.

I know I can freeze salsa.  Everything I've read says the thawed salsa loses its texture and is best to be incorporated into something.  It also says that it gets watery and the flavors all blend together.

OK, that sounds great, but then I think of spaghetti sauce, chili, lasagna, or soup.  None of those sound good with the addition of cherries.  I think I could make the roasted/smoky flavor work in any of those, but cherry spaghetti?  Or cherry chili?

I thought about a dessert pasta sauce (for chocolate pasta), but the garlic, cilantro, and major smoky taste veto that idea.  The only thing I can come up with is a borscht hybrid, but I'm not crazy about beets.

Does anyone have any suggestions that I might be able to incorporate my thawed roasted cherry salsa into?  Or are the reviews of thawed salsa not right and it really does taste good?

I did think about canning the leftover salsa, but it seems like that might make it lose more of its texture and flavor than freezing.

Comment: Canning would definitely keep the texture better than freezing.

Comment: @Jay, would canning make the flavors all meld together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about pureeing it and using it as a base for BBQ sauce or a basting sauce for roasts.

Comment: That'll let you reduce it if it gets watery, too!

Comment: It's already frozen, so that sounds like a great way to repurpose it.  Thanks Debbie!